# Gauss Seidel (Specific equation solver) in C

Tags: c

Apologies for posting a badly formed question prior to this attempt.

I'm trying to get a Gauss Seidel method to work in C, to check how much quicker it is than higher level interpreted languages (i.e python), but I'm having some issues with the results that I'm obtaining.

My input matrix is

- Symmetric Positive-Definitive
- & Diagonally dominant

so I believe it should converge.

The problem attempts to solve "Ax=b" ,

(Where 'A' = 'a[ ][ ]' ,'b' = 'b[ ]', and 'x'= 'x[ ]')

The final array 'check [ ]' is obtained via a dot product between 'a' and 'x' to see if it returns something close to 'b'.

The below code is fully executable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


int main(void) 
{   
int i=0,j=0;
int num=0;

double h = 1.0/(3+1);
double h2 = pow(h,2);
double w=1.5, sum=0.0;

long double x[9],y[9], check[9];
long double tol = pow(10, -10);
long double  a[9][9] = {{-4, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} ,
                        {1, -4, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0} ,
                        {0, 1, -4, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0} ,
                        {1, 0, 0, -4, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0} ,
                        {0, 1, 0, 1, -4, 1, 0, 1, 0} ,
                        {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, -4, 0, 0, 1} ,
                        {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -4, 1, 0} ,
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, -4, 1} ,
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, -4}};


long double b[9] =   {0.000000,
                      0.000000,
                      0.000000,
                      0.000000,
                      0.125000,
                      0.000000,
                      0.000000,
                      0.000000,
                      0.000000 };



for(i=0;i<9;i++){               // initialise the arrays to 0
    x[i]=0;
    y[i]=2*tol;                 
}   


for(i=0;i<9;i++){               // prints 'a' matrix, to check if its right
    for(j=0;j<9;j++){
        printf("a[%d][%d] = %LF ",i,j,a[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n" );
}

printf("\n\n");

for(i=0;i<9;i++){               // prints b matrix 
    printf("b[%d] = %LF \n",i,b[i]);
}

do{                             // the Gauss seidel Solver
    for(i =0;i<9;i++){
        for(j=0; j<9; j++){
            if(i!=j){
                sum += a[i][j]*x[j];
            }
            x[i] = (w/a[i][i])* (b[i] - sum + a[i][i]*x[i]) + (1-w)*x[i];   
        }
    }
num=num+1;
}while (fabs(y[i]-x[i])>tol);

printf("\n\n\n"); 

for(i=0;i<9;i++){               // Prints the solution X
    printf("x[%d] = %LF \n",i,x[i]);
}

printf("\n\n");

for(i=0;i<9;i++){               // Ititialises matrix 
        check[i]=0;
}

for (i = 0; i < 9; i++){        // performs a dot product of
                                // 'a' and 'x', to see if we get
                                // 'b' as the result 
    for(j = 0; j< 9; j++){
        check[i]+= a[i][j] * x[j];
    }   
    check[i] = check[i]/h2;     // the 'b' matrix was multiplied by h2, 
                                // hence to get it back, a division is necessary
    printf("check[%d] = %LF\n",i,check[i]);
}

printf("num=%d\n",num );
return 0;

}
```

The output i.e 'x' that I get is:

```
x[0] = -0.000000 
x[1] = -0.000000 
x[2] = -0.000000 
x[3] = -0.000000 
x[4] = -0.421875 
x[5] = -0.791016 
x[6] = -1.423828 
x[7] = -3.816650 
x[8] = -11.702087
```

and the output for 'Check' I get is:

```
check[0] = 0.000000
check[1] = -4.500000
check[2] = -5.625000
check[3] = -14.625000
check[4] = -10.968750
check[5] = -42.328125
check[6] = 17.156250
check[7] = 18.421875
check[8] = 212.343750
```

Ideally, if everything works, check[4] should output 2 (the reason for which is given in a comment in the code when outputting 'check'), and every other element of check should be 0.

Any suggestions?

Comment: *"how much quicker it is than other interpreted languages"* C is not an interpreted langauge.

Comment: I'm sorry i was unclear about that, i meant languages such as python. I'll correct it now

Comment: when the do-while checks `(fabs(x[i] - y[i]) < tol)` `i=9` which is out of bounds. what is your intended exit criteria?

Comment: the interior for loop has `i < 9`, would it exceed that? I didn't consider that `i` would be equal to `9` at all, there is no exit criteria there.

Comment: Because `i==9` following the loop `for(i =0;i<9;i++)`, clearly the loop terminates because `i>=9`.

Comment: @namehttp404, yes `i = 9`, the loop exits when `i < 9` is no longer true. What I mean by exit criteria is how you decide it has converged. what did you intend the line `fabs(..) < tol` to do.

Comment: @rpattiso I see, I didn't consider that. I decide it has converged when the difference between the current `x` element and the `y` element _(which are all the same)_ is smaller than the given tolerance.  In other words, if any element is smaller than 2* the tolerance (**y is 2 * tol**), then the loop exits

Comment: @WeatherVane do you have any alternate methods in which i could implement that with?

Comment: I don't know which element you are testing, because `while (fabs(y[i]-x[i])>tol);` doesn't test any of them.

Comment: is `y` the suppose to be optimal solution?

Comment: (ideally) if the maximum element in `x` is less than tolerance... exit the loop.

But that can only be achieved if I have a for loop inside the exit condition, so I improvised it instead

Comment: You are not checking `x[i]` but the diff with `y[i]`, and you need to check the maximum (minimum?) difference for every element in the `i` loop.

Comment: okay, I'll modify that and update you on the results.

Comment: okay I completely changed the criteria, by making it run 25 times, instead of checking it for a tolerance. I applied the tolerance method because I used the same thing in python, and it seemed to converge in 22 iterations _(thats why I made the program run 25 times, by having a variable count down in the `do..while` loop, with the condition `while (n>0)`)_ .

Comment: You posted before I could write this: I have tried comparing the min difference but the `do..while` loop still does not terminate (I didn't mention that). Now I see that every `y[]` element is `2*tol` so I'm confused as to what the exit condition is. Did you mean to compare `x[]` elements with the previous iteration? In which case you need to copy `x[]` to `y[]` before computing and comparing the difference.

Comment: the python code im trying to implement is in the following link [link](http://textuploader.com/651w)

Comment: it takes more code to access a stack variable than to access a global address space variable.  the arrays 'a' and 'b' are never changed.  suggest those two arrays be moved to file global space and given a 'static' and 'const' modifiers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sum` should be reinitialized to 0 inside the for-loop before starting the next row and the equation is incorrect. The equation you are using from the python implementation assumes that  `a[i][i]*x[i]` was added to make the full dot-product, they used `numpy` to get the dot product instead of looping so they had no opportunity to do `i != j`. Also I'm not sure the equation in that implementation is the Gauss Seidel method, it looks more like Successive Over Relaxation because of the `w` and `(1 - w)`. Anyway, here is my modified solution. I check for convergence using the error, |Ax - b| < tol for all entries. The for-loop is split into two as a small optimization. `a[i][i] * x[i]` is added to `sum` to get the current value for (Ax)<sub>i</sub> in the error check.

```
int converged;                                                                  
do {                                                                
  converged = 1;                                                                    
  for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {                                                         
    sum = 0;                                                                       
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      sum += a[i][j] * x[j];
    }                                 
    for (j = i + 1; j < 9; j++) {
      sum += a[i][j] * x[j];
    }                             
    x[i] += w * ((b[i] - sum) / a[i][i] - x[i]);                                   
    if (fabs(sum + a[i][i] * x[i] - b[i]) > tol) {
      converged = 0;
    }                    
  }                                                                      
} while (!converged);
```

which gives the output:

```
x[0] = -0.007812 
x[1] = -0.015625 
x[2] = -0.007812 
x[3] = -0.015625 
x[4] = -0.046875 
x[5] = -0.015625 
x[6] = -0.007812 
x[7] = -0.015625 
x[8] = -0.007813 


check[0] = 0.000000
check[1] = -0.000000
check[2] = -0.000000
check[3] = -0.000000
check[4] = 2.000000
check[5] = 0.000000
check[6] = -0.000000
check[7] = 0.000000
check[8] = 0.000000
num=31
```

Comment: I'm speechless. I've been looking at the same code for about 9 hours now without a solution. I cannot thank you, and everyone who tried helping me, enough.

Comment: did you use the same tolerance i.e `tol=10e-10` ? or did you change it?

Comment: please ignore the above.

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of those following along at home. I suggest reading with the [wikipedia article on Gauss-Seigel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method). I will attempt to explain what the algorithm is doing, and provide C code that implements the algorithm.

The Python example in the wikipedia page uses this simple example for matrix A and B

```
    | 10  -1   2   0 |          |   6 |
A = | -1  11  -1   3 |      B = |  25 |
    |  2  -1  10  -1 |          | -11 |
    |  0   3  -1   8 |          |   8 |
```

Those matrices represent the following system of equations

```
10*x1 -    x2 +  2*x3        =   6  
  -x1 + 11*x2 -    x3 + 3*x4 =  25
 2*x1 -    x2 + 10*x3 -   x4 = -11  
         3*x2 -    x3 + 8*x4 =  15
```

The solution that we're trying to find with Gauss-Seigel is

```
x1=1   x2=2   x3= -1   x4=1
```

---

So how does the algorithm work? Well first take a wild a guess at the answer, e.g.

```
x1=0   x2=0   x3=0   x4=0
```

Then plug those guesses into the equations and try to improve the guesses. Specifically, plug the values for x2,x3,x4 into the first equation, and then compute a new value for x1.

```
10*x1 - 0 + 0 = 6    ==>    x1 = 6/10 = 0.6
```

Then plug the *new* value of x1, and the old values of x3,x4 into the second equation to get an improved guess for x2

```
-0.6 + 11*x2 - 0 + 0 = 25    ==>    11*x2 = 25.6    ==>    x2 = 2.327273
```

And for x3 and x4

```
2*0.6 - 2.327273 + 10*x3 - 0 = -11    ==>    10*x3 = -9.872727    ==>     x3 = -0.987273
3*2.327273 + 0.987273 + 8*x4 =  15    ==>     8*x4 =  7.030908    ==>     x4 =  0.878864
```

So after one iteration of Gauss-Seigel, the improved guess at the answer is

```
x1=0.6   x2=2.327273   x3= -0.987273   x4=0.878864
```

The algorithm continues until either the solution converges or the maximum number of iterations is exceeded.

---

Here's what the code looks like in C. The counter `k` limits the number of iterations (just in case the solution doesn't converge). The Gauss-Seidel method is applied by evaluating each of the equations while skipping `X[i]`. Then the new value for `X[i]` is computed.  The code displays the new values of `X[]`, and the checks if the answer is good enough by evaluating each equation and verifying that the sum is within epsilon of `B[i]`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define SIZE 4

double A[SIZE][SIZE] = {
    { 10, -1,  2,  0 },
    { -1, 11, -1,  3 },
    {  2, -1, 10, -1 },
    {  0,  3, -1,  8 }
};

double B[SIZE] = { 6, 25, -11, 15 };
double X[SIZE] = { 0,  0,   0,  0 };

int main( void )
{
    int i, j, k, done;
    double sum;

    done = 0;
    for ( k = 0; k < 100 && !done; k++ )
    {
        // perform the next iteration of Gauss-Seidel
        for ( i = 0; i < SIZE; i++ )
        {
            sum = 0;
            for ( j = 0; j < SIZE; j++ )
                if ( j != i )
                    sum += A[i][j] * X[j];

            X[i] = (B[i] - sum) / A[i][i];
        }

        // print the k'th iteration of X[]
        printf( "%2d --", k );
        for ( i = 0; i < SIZE; i++ )
            printf( " %lf", X[i] );
        printf( "\n" );

        // check for convergence
        done = 1;
        for ( i = 0; i < SIZE; i++ )
        {
            sum = 0;
            for ( j = 0; j < SIZE; j++ )
                sum += A[i][j] * X[j];

            if ( fabs( B[i] - sum ) > 1e-6 )
            {
                done = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```